# Use QStorageInfo to get name of network drives

Tags: c++, qt, filesystems

I've got a problem with `QStorageInfo` on Windows 7. I use `QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()` to get a list of all mounted Volumes. It work. Then I want so display the Volume labels. My Windows explorer show me this:

```
System (C:)
BackUp (D:)
Nas01 (\\NAS01)(X:)
Code (\\Nas02\Code\)(Z:)
```

But my console output is this:

```
System ( C:/ )
BackUp ( D:/ )
NAS01-N ( X:/ )
NAS01-N ( Z:/ )
```

This is the code:

```
foreach(QStorageInfo i, QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()){
    qDebug() << i.name() << "(" << i.rootPath() << ")";
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try using i.device () instead. Depending on what your exact needs are, you may need to do some post-processing on the results, but the "device" method returns the network path.

Comment: I'ts a good advice, thanks. A little step closer but not really what I want. Because my drive `Z:` is mapped to `\\nas01\code` but i could name it `Harry` if i want by simply rename it inside the windows explorer (F2). How to get this label text?